# How do I use characters that are not supported by default in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

I am trying to use characters such as `á` and `ô` in a python generated PDF. The program uses the dateutil module (and several others) to generate a PDF calendar (with images). The calendar is laid out with Latex.

My aim is to create calendars in French, but the array of month names in French includes characters which appear to be not recognised by python.

During generation the program prints `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: unexpected end of data` in the command line.

How can I tell python to use these characters?

If it helps the array is:

```
FRENCH_MONTHS = [u'NotAMonth', u'Janvier', u'Février', u'Mars', u'Avril', u'Mai', u'Juin', u'Juillet', u'Aôut', u'Septembre', u'Octobre', u'Novembre', u'Décembre']
```

Also used:

- MPS to PDF converter

Comment: Python supports the full unicode database.

Comment: Where does the problem lie? In writing the characters in the Python script? Or in adding them to the PDF (i.e., a problem with the PDF library)? Also, which PDF library are you using, and can you edit your question to include the code you've written so far?

Comment: @user1833746 so I have heard. It may be some other problem in how the program is doing thing, or what I have done along the way. But I did not write the program and do not have sufficent knowledge depth in python to find out how the program does what it does.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the source encoding used to create your python source.  Do this by adding a [source encoding declaration](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations):

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

This should be the first or second line of your python source file. The encoding *has* to match the encoding you saved the file in; check your text editor settings. The error message you added to your question indicates that the encoding doesn't match, I suspect you used latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) instead.

Alternatively, use unicode escapes to include non-ASCII characters; `u'\u00e9'` represents the e with accent grave in a as a unicode code point.

Please do study up on how Python handles Unicode in the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). The [Joel Spolsky Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is also *essential* reading for any software developer dealing with any non-ASCII data.

Comment: @ If the `coding`line was the error, it would report a different exception.

Comment: @glglgl Indeed, this answer was written before the question included the all-important error message!

Comment: @glglgl: The question was edited.

Comment: I tested that line in a file and got a `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details` which is a different text, thus my comment. But maybe it is just because of different interpreter versions?

Comment: @glglgl: The OP had not reported any *proper* error *including a traceback* yet. :-P But yes, it's probably interpreter dependent on what the error reported is.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the `# coding: UTF-8` if your editor is setup to use save the file with the correct encoding

Alternatively you can also encode the characters in to their ASCII-only escape sequence. For example, the [escape-sequence for `é`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) is `\u00E9`:

```
FRENCH_MONTHS = [u'NotAMonth', u'Janvier', u'F\u00E9vrier', ...]
```

This is less likely to be messed up by a badly configured editor, but achieves the exact same thing.

Even better, you could use the [`calendar`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module and sidestep the entire issue (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037370/python-calendar-day-month-names-in-specific-locale)):

```
import calendar


def get_month_names(locale):
    with calendar.TimeEncoding(locale) as encoding:
        months = list(calendar.month_name)

        # Could do this to match original values:
        # months = [x.title() for x in months]

        if encoding is not None:
            months = [x.decode(encoding) for x in months]

        months[0] = u"NotAMonth"
        return months

FRENCH_MONTHS = get_month_names("fr_FR.UTF-8")
```

---

Edit: This is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte) - your é is encoded with `latin 1`, but your Python source-file encoding is UTF-8 (either explicitly set in Python 2, or because it's the default in Python 3):

```
>>> print "\xe9".decode("latin1")
é
>>> print "\xe9".decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Another good reason for using one of the alternative solutions above!