# Python locale error: unsupported locale setting

Tags: python, locale

Why do I get the following error when doing this in python:

```
>>> import locale
>>> print str( locale.getlocale() )
(None, None)
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 531, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

This works with other locales like fr or nl as well. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Update: Doing the following did not yield anything:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have a `de_DE` listed in `locale -a`? If not you must [install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=196414) it.

Comment: Related: a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/specialunderwear/1218856) to install all locales on Ubuntu.

Comment: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` is wrong. You need `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')`.

Comment: You can sometimes discover an available encoding for the language/country you want using the built-in aliases:  `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale.locale_aliases['de_DE'])`.

Comment: I found the most appropriate answer here --> https://linuxpip.org/fix-python-locale-error/

Answer (score 735):

Run following commands

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It will solve this.

Make sure to match the `.UTF-8` part to the actual syntax found in the output of `locale -a` e.g. `.utf8` on some systems.

Comment: I didn't have to use the dpkg command. After all, if the problem is occurring locally, then real solution would be to add the first two commands to your startup applications.

Comment: This didn't work for me.
`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`
failed with 
`-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`

What worked was doing this:
`export LC_ALL=C`

Answer (score 249):

According to [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1249131), it solved by entering this command:

> export LC_ALL=C

Comment: What does it mean? - ok it sets an environment varibale `LC_ALL` to the valuue `'C'` - but why schould this work?

Comment: Why LC_ALL works --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: I search and try this every time when I change the computer and this works every time while other methods don't.

Answer (score 240):

You probably do not have any `de_DE` locale available.

You can view a list of available locales with the `locale -a` command.
For example, on my machine:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
it_CH.utf8
it_IT.utf8
POSIX
```

Note that if you want to set the locale to `it_IT` you must also specify the `.utf8`:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it_IT')   # error!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'it_IT.utf8')
'it_IT.utf8'
```

To install a new locale use:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-id
```

where `id` is the language code (taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale))

*After* you have installed the locale you should follow Julien Palard advice and reconfigure the locales with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: That did not work in my Debian docker-container. But this worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-debian-ubuntu-docker-container

Answer (score 54):

One of the above answer provides the solution:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

**The problem with above solution is that it has to be done on the linux shell.** However, if you are providing your code to work on the client machine then this is a bad approach. 
I also tried executing the above commands using os.system(), but still it doesn't work.

**Solution that worked for me is**

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 35):

More permanent solution would be to fill the missing values, in the output shown by command: `locale`

Output from `locale` is:

```
 $ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.utf8
LC_TIME=es_ES.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.utf8
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

To Fill the missing values edit ~/.bashrc :

```
 $ vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following lines after the above command (suppose you want en_US.UTF-8 to be your language):

```
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

If this file is ReadOnly you would be needing to follow the  steps mentioned by [The GeekyBoy](http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/629). The answer given by [Dr Beco in Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/694450/using-vim-to-force-edit-a-file-when-you-opened-without-permissions) has details relating to saving readonly files.

After saving the file do:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you wont be facing the same problem anymore.

Answer (score 16):

If you're on a Debian (or Debian fork), you can add locales using :

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Does the `dpkg-reconfigure locales` bring you a local choosing menu like this one : http://www.vpser.net/uploads/2013/01/dpkg-reconfigure-locales-1.jpg ?

Comment: Nope. I just get the output I posted in the update of my question.

Answer (score 12):

You error clearly says, you are trying to use locale something was not there.

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

**locale.Error: unsupported locale setting**

**To check available setting, use** `locale -a`

```
deb@deb-Latitude-E7470:/ambot$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

so you can use one among,

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_AG.utf8')
'en_AG.utf8'
>>>
```

for `de_DE`

This file can either be adjusted manually or updated using the tool, update-locale.

```
update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: I want to add `persian - farsi` to my `locale`. I run `sudo update-locale LANG=fa_IR` and `sudo update-locale LANG=fa_IR.UTF-8` in terminal. nothing happens. not an error nor a completion notification. what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

On Arch Linux I was able to fix this by running `sudo locale-gen`

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I had this same problem, but none of the solutions worked.
I had upgraded my computer and migrated my PC. I had a a mixed locale english and spanish:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.utf8
LC_TIME=es_ES.utf8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.utf8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=es_ES.utf8
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

But, on my new Debian installation, I just selected english as locale. 
Which finally worked was to reconfigure locales package to add and generate spanish too.

```
$ grep -v "#" /etc/locale.gen 
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the easiest way to setup the local locale in python{,3} is:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'de_DE.UTF-8'
```

Then, locale aware stuff just works, if you're on a decent linux distro, and should work on binary distributions of the other OSes as well (or that's a bug IMHO).

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> print(dt.date.today().strftime("%A %d. %B %Y"))
Sonntag 11. Dezember 2016
```

Answer (score 4):

Place it in the `Dockerfile` above the `ENV`.

```
# make the "en_US.UTF-8" locale so postgres will be utf-8 enabled by default
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the other solutions (dpkg-reconfigure locales, locale-gen) and nothing else worked in my debian:9 container. Is this really a / the standard way to create the en_US.UTF-8 locale?

Comment: Yes, I think its the standard way en_US.UTF-8 locale. When you run `locale` in terminal u get `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and other locale? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394101/pip-install-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

Just open the .bashrc file and add this

> export LC_ALL=C

and then type source .bashrc in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

- run this command
  `locale` to get what locale is used. Such as:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>   LANGUAGE=en_US:en
>   LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
>   LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
>   LC_ALL=

- search for the listed locales list in first step in `/etc/locale-gen` file. Uncomment to used ones
- run `locale-gen` to generate newly added locales

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur, if you have just added a new locale. You need to restart the python interactive shell (`quit(`) and `python`) to get access to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use BABEL: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html

I got the same issue here using Docker, I've tried every single step and didn't work well, always getting locale error, so I decided to use BABEL, and everything worked well.

Answer (score 1):

python looks for .UFT-8, but you probably have .utf8
try installing the .UFT-8 packages with sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

Answer (score 1):

For those deploying a docker image and using a locale that isn't shown in the `locale -a` command, add this line to your Dockerfile
`RUN apt-get install -y locales`

This should add all locales to your image, I used de_DE which is not part of AWS default Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to get python to [spit out names in specific locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037370/python-calendar-day-month-names-in-specific-locale) I landed here with same problem.

In pursuing the answer, things got a little mystical I find.

I found that python code.

```
import locale
print locale.getdefaultlocale()
>> ('en_DK', 'UTF-8')
```

And indeed `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_DK.UTF-8')` works

Using tips here I tested further to see what is available using python code

```
import locale
loc_list = [(a,b) for a,b in locale.locale_alias.items() ]
loc_size = len(loc_list)
print loc_size,'entries'

for loc in loc_list:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, loc[1])
        print 'SUCCES set {:12} ({})'.format(loc[1],loc[0])
    except:
        pass
```

which yields

```
858 entries
SUCCES set en_US.UTF-8  (univ)
SUCCES set C            (c.ascii)
SUCCES set C            (c.en)
SUCCES set C            (posix-utf2)
SUCCES set C            (c)
SUCCES set C            (c_c)
SUCCES set C            (c_c.c)
SUCCES set en_IE.UTF-8  (en_ie.utf8@euro)
SUCCES set en_US.UTF-8  (universal.utf8@ucs4)
SUCCES set C            (posix)
SUCCES set C            (english_united-states.437)
SUCCES set en_US.UTF-8  (universal)
```

Of which only above is working! But the `en_DK.UTF-8` is not in this list, though it works!?!? What??
And the python generated locale list do contain a lot of combos of da and DK, which I am looking for, but again no UTF-8 for da/DK...

I am on a Point Linux distro (Debian based), and here `locale` says amongst other `LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"`, which I know works, but not the locale I need.

`locale -a` says

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_DK.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

So definitely need to [install other locale](https://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian), which i did by editing `/etc/locale.gen`, uncomment needed line `da_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8` and run command `locale-gen`

Now `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'da_DK.UTF-8')` works too, and I can get my localized day and month names.

**My Conclision:**

Python : locale.locale_alias is not at all helpfull in finding available locales!!!

Linux : It is quite easy to get locale list and install new locale. A lot of help available.

Windows : I have been investigating a little, but nothing conclusive. There are though posts leading to answers, but I have not felt the urge to pursue it.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, the main source of error here is the exact syntax of the locale-name. Especially as it seems to differ between distributions.
I've seen mentioned here in different answers/comments:

```
de_DE.utf8
de_DE.UTF-8
```

Even though this is obviously the same for a human being, the same does not hold for your standard deterministic algorithm.

So you will probably do something along the lines of:

```
DESIRED_LOCALE=de
DESIRED_LOCALE_COUNTRY=DE
DESIRED_CODEPAGE_RE=\.[Uu][Tt][Ff].?8
if [ $(locale -a | grep -cE "${DESIRED_LOCALE}_${DESIRED_LOCALE_COUNTRY}${DESIRED_CODEPAGE_RE}") -eq 1 ]
then
    export LC_ALL=$(locale -a | grep -m1 -E "${DESIRED_LOCALE}_${DESIRED_LOCALE_COUNTRY}${DESIRED_CODEPAGE_RE}")
    export LANG=$LC_ALL
else
    echo "Not exactly one desired locale definition found: $(locale -a | grep -E "${DESIRED_LOCALE}_${DESIRED_LOCALE_COUNTRY}${DESIRED_CODEPAGE_RE}")" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

first, make sure you have the language pack installed by doing :

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base


sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: the english languagepack is installed per default - furthermore the answer is allready given here and this one lacks in formating.

Answer (score -3):

**Not the answer for this question but this question helped me to find the answer for my problem.**

I had this problem when using inside a Docker container.
I solved by installing **locales**, adding my language to the **locale.gen** file, executing **locale-gen** (it reads from locale.gen) and finally setting **LANG** to my language.

For example, my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN echo "pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
RUN locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `RUN  sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && export LC_ALL=C && locale-gen` did.