# Missing en_US locale required for python

Tags: python, debian, locale, apt

I'm not sure if this a good place to ask for help with this error. Somehow I seem not to have a locale on my Debian Linux system. Basically, I became aware of this when a python program I was trying to run executed the line `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')`. I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "runserver.py", line 4, in 
>       site = TarbellSite(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)))
>     File "/home/brian/.virtualenvs/tarbell/src/flask-tarbell/tarbell/app.py", line 36, in **init**
>       self.projects = self.load_projects()
>     File "/home/brian/.virtualenvs/tarbell/src/flask-tarbell/tarbell/app.py", line 59, in load_projects
>       project = imp.load_module(name, filename, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/brian/Code/contrib/tarbell/base/config.py", line 28, in 
>       locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
>     File "/home/brian/.virtualenvs/tarbell/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 547, in setlocale
>       return _setlocale(category, locale)
>   locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

However, researching relevant extant questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/) one, tells me to run `locale -a`, which yields:

> C
>   C.UTF-8
>   en_US.utf8
>   POSIX

So, it looks like US english IS in the locales on my system. What am I doing wrong? I am running into various other road blocks. `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en` according to a lot of places on the internet gets the english language pack. But apt complains that this package doesn't exist. How do I get this damn locale?

Comment: First, `en_US.utf8` is not the same thing as `en_US` any more than either of them is `en`.

Comment: Meanwhile, it looks like it's getting that `en_US` out of some configuration file, so why not try just figuring out which configuration file, and setting it to `en_US.utf8` (which you _do_ have) instead of `en_US` and see if that works?

Comment: Finally, what version of Debian do you have? Haven't Debian and Debian-related systems have used the standard `en_US.UTF-8` names for a long time now?

Comment: I see! I know that en_US.UTF-8 is different than en_US, I just wasn't looking at which it was that was being used in my stack trace. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I found it, and got it working. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add the 'utf8' bit as well;

```
import locale
locale.getlocale()
>>> (None, None)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
>>> 'en_US.utf8'
locale.getlocale()
>>> ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Right. I'll try to see where it's being called, I suppose.

Comment: Got it working, thanks much. I was trying to get an app working that I expected to work out of the box. However, thinking about it now, all I did was pull a git repository, and on the computer that originally ran the app, 'en_US' probably existed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

I am using an iMac with OS X 10.11.6 (15G19009)
Python version 3.5.2

I tried:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'') <-- this line worked fine on windows 7
```

The Solution for the MAC was to specify English like this:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'EN_US') <-- this line produced the desired results
```

These two lines must be os independent.  after further testing this is a cross platform solution, you can adapt this to any platform by simply calling platform.platform and making the necessary changes.

```
import locale
import platform
if (platform.platform(aliased = 0, terse = 0)=='Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit'):
    locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'EN_US' )
else:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')
```

Comment: you might also look up the debian specific locale information here:  https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

Answer (score 0):

This is a more eloquent answer:

```
import platform
import locale
system = platform.system() ##<-- to get the platform you are using.
if (system == 'Darwin'): ##<-- Darwin has Different naming
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'EN_US') ##<-- Default us english on Darwin
else: ##<-- if system isn't Darwin 
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'') ##<-- this works for Windows and Debian
## operations like locale.currency ect......
```

This code allows for multi-platform development the error displayed in this post was improper setting of locale. This answer allows for at least 3 different platforms to set locale correctly using only standard modules.