# How to translate pygtk; glade; gtk.Builder() application?

Tags: gtk, interface-builder, locale, pygtk, glade

This is my first trial in translating `pygtk` `glade`; I have created Rockdome.mo file on the following dir:`./locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/Rockdome.mo`

```
    def apply_locale(self , lang):
         domain  = "Rockdome"
         local_path = basefolder+"/locale"   # basefolder is the current dir
         lang = gettext.translation('Rockdome', local_path ,  languages=['%s'%lang])
         lang.install()
         _ = lang.gettext
         print _("Close") # the output is اغلاق which is correct arabic translation!!
```

but the application still appear in the default system lamnguage `EN`; What I missing ??

### EDIT

After searching in pygtk and buider tutoial; I found 2 methods to tell `gtk` & `builder` How to bring text :
the first from [here](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq22.002.htp) :

```
 for module in (gettext, gtk.glade):
     module.bindtextdomain(APP_NAME, LOCALE_DIR)
     module.textdomain(APP_NAME)
```

which fail.

---

The second from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.9/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-set-translation-domain)

```
 self.builder.set_translation_domain('Rockdome')
 print self.builder.get_translation_domain() # the output is "Rockdome"
```

which also fail !!, the application still untranslated !!

> N.B: I guess that `builder` needs to know the location for my local path to search in it not in the default paths
>   so I copied `./local/ar/LC_MESSAGES/Rockdome.mo` to `/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/Rockdome.mo` which also failed.

Comment: It prints the correct output to console but not in the app?

Comment: Yes, the console output is correct arabic translation from *.mo file

Comment: You need to return `lang` at the moment you are just changing it in the function.

Comment: `return lang` so that you can set it in your app.

Comment: Excuse me; I am beginner; could you suggest code?

Comment: I added an answer =) Hope it helps. If it does we can delete the comments.

Comment: The returned lang should passed to what ??

Comment: My __init__ containonly  `apply_locale("ar")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55953/discussion-between-esnadr-and-the-cthulhu-kid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following method works succefully with me >

1. use `locale` module not `gettext`.
2. execute `locale.setlocale(category , language )`
3. Set the `translation_domain` of `gtk.Builder` by `gtk.Builder.set_translation_domain()` before loading glade file by : EX:`gtk.Builder.add_from_file`

### Code ##

```
    import locale
    from locale import gettext as _

    def apply_locale(self , current_lang ):
        domain  = "Rockdome"
        local_path = basefolder+"/data/locale"
        locale.bindtextdomain(domain , local_path )
        locale.textdomain(domain)
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ar_AE.utf8')   
        # note that language is "ar_AE.utf8" not "ar" or "ar_AE"
        self.builder.set_translation_domain(domain )
```

---

### Why we should replace gettext with locale

> Thanks to Juha Sahakangas on the #gtk+ IRC channel for providing the explanation:
>   For this particular case the locale module needs to be used instead of gettext.
>   Python's gettext module is pure python, it doesn't actually set the text domain in a way that the C library can read, but locale does (by calling libc).
>   So long as that's done, GtkBuilder already works the way you're asking it to.

---

### Notes

to avoid `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

1. In the function locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, language ); `language` should be one the supported languages.
2. to get list of supported languages; `locale -a` command.
3. The name of the language should be equal to its name in the output of the command `locale -a`; ie. don't strip the encode if it included in the language name, ie:. `ar_AE.utf8` doesn't equal to `ar_AE`.
4. If the `language` doesn't supported; we can install it.
5. To install unsupported language:

> sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

### Thanks for this links

[how to make glade load translation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140552/how-to-make-glade-load-translations-from-opt)

[locale error : unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

[locale module doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#access-to-message-catalogs)

[install unsupported locale](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale)

Comment: In my installation 'locale' module doesn't have 'gettext'. I have a Windows7 machine, with Python 2.7.8. This snippet from `locale` doc explains why: `The locale module exposes the C library’s gettext interface on systems that provide this interface.`

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing the `lang` object within the scope of the function. You have to return it to set it properly.

You need to call your function like this: `my_lang = apply_locale(lang)` or you could set `lang` as a property of the class.

```
def apply_locale(self , lang):
     domain  = "Rockdome"
     local_path = basefolder+"/locale"   # basefolder is the current dir
     lang = gettext.translation('Rockdome', local_path ,  languages=['%s'%lang])
     lang.install()
     _ = lang.gettext
     return lang  # Here you return the value and set it to the object you passed to your function.
```

Your use of the variable name here is confusing. You are changing the argument to a completely different type of object, you might want to differentiate between the two.

Comment: please, refer to the question; `self.builder.set_translationdomain() `