# Python atof with local input

Tags: python, number-formatting

Say, I have a (German) expression which reads `10.401,40 (in Mio EUR)`, I'd like to convert this to a real float (in this case around 10 billions) in Python.
This is what I have thus far:

```
import re, locale
from locale import *
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE') 

string = "10.401,40 (in Mio EUR)"
m = re.search(r'([\d.,]+)', string)
if m is not None:
    number = atof(m.group(1)) * 10**6
```

However, it raises a `ValueError` (`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 10.401.40`).
Why? Isn't the `.setlocale()` directive supposed to be handling exactly this? Is there a pythonic way that I am (yet!) unaware of?

Comment: Your code works for me in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Your snippet and traceback don't match

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Why not? I copied it from the console.

Comment: How does `10.401,40` become `10.401.40`?

Comment: Your example works fine on my machine... Are you sure you have the de_DE locale installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same `ValueError`. As [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting) explains, you need to have the German locale installed in your system. Following the above, I typed in `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selected `de-DE.UTF-8`. I had to modify the locale setting line to match with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')` and got your snippet to run. Good luck!