# pip install - locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, pip

Full stacktrace:

```
➜  ~ pip install virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/locale.py", line 592, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

On the same server, I successfully ran `pip install virtualenv` with python 2.7.x.

Now, I've just installed python3.4 using `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.4`.

```
➜  ~ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

`pip uninstall virtualenv` throws the same error too

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting) yet?

Comment: yes I have @idjaw, node that it's an empty string in my case, it's different from the wrong locale you pointed out

Comment: Yeah, I did notice that. Did you try the pkg-reconfigure?

Comment: my server is centos, not Ubuntu @idjaw, I've checked and there seems to be nothing wrong with the local it's `LANG=en_GB.utf8`

Answer (score 663, accepted):

The root cause is: your environment variable `LC_ALL` is missing or invalid somehow

**Short answer-**

just run the following command:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
```

If you keep getting the error in new terminal windows, add it at the bottom of your `.bashrc` file.

**Long answer-**

Here is my `locale` settings:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

*Python2.7*

```
    $ uname -a
    Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.9
    $ pip --version
    pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
    $ unset LC_ALL
    $ pip install virtualenv
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 579, in setlocale
        return _setlocale(category, locale)
    locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
    $ export LC_ALL=C
    $ pip install virtualenv
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Comment: so it's just a matter of setting up an environment variable then? Do you know why I have never encountered this before? Shouldn't this value be set automatically?

Comment: @eric Hi, I just update my post. This problem does happen with python2.7 on my computer.

Comment: very interesting indeed @ROY, I've had 2 other almost-indentical-to-this-server servers set up and they haven been working perfectly fine

Comment: I've encountered this using letsencrypt-auto, and `export LC_ALL=C` helped.

Comment: If you're wondering what `LC_ALL=C` means, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

Comment: The short answer "LC_ALL=C" is more than enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

Run the following command (it will work):

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: (-1) The `dpkg-reconfigure` command is intended for use on Debian based systems. This question is tagged with `centos`, an RHEL derivative which does not provide support for dpkg unless you enable the `epel-release` repository, and install the `dpkg-devel` & `dpkg-dev` packages. Even then, this is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 32):

Someone may find it useful. You could put those locale settings in .bashrc file, which usually located in the home directory.
Just add this command in .bashrc:
`export LC_ALL=C`
then type `source .bashrc`
Now you don't need to call this command manually every time, when you connecting via ssh for example.

Answer (score 4):

While you can set the locale exporting an env variable, you will have to do that every time you start a session. Setting a locale this way will solve the problem permanently:

```
sudo apt-get install locales
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/default/locale
```

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or are you using `sudo` on the same line that you try to install it? `sudo apt-get install ... sudo ...`

Comment: @CyberEd , you're right, I've edited the example to remove unneeded dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

**[This answer is target on linux platform only]**

The first thing you should know is most of the locale config file located path can be get from `localedef --help` :

```
$ localedef --help | tail -n 5
System's directory for character maps : /usr/share/i18n/charmaps
                       repertoire maps: /usr/share/i18n/repertoiremaps
                       locale path    : /usr/lib/locale:/usr/share/i18n
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>
```

See the last `/usr/share/i18n` ? This is where your xx_XX.UTF-8 config file located:

```
$ ls /usr/share/i18n/locales/zh_*
/usr/share/i18n/locales/zh_CN  /usr/share/i18n/locales/zh_HK  /usr/share/i18n/locales/zh_SG  /usr/share/i18n/locales/zh_TW
```

Now what ? We need to compile them into archive binary. One of the way, e.g. assume I have `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_LOVE`, I can add it into compile list, i.e. `/etc/locale-gen` file:

```
$ tail -1 /etc/locale.gen 
en_LOVE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

And compile it to binary with `sudo locale-gen`:

```
$ sudo locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  ...
  en_LOVE.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

And now update the system default locale with desired `LANG`, `LC_ALL` ...etc with this `update-locale`:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_LOVE.UTF-8
```

`update-locale` actually also means to update this `/etc/default/locale` file which will source by system on login to setup environment variables:

```
$ head /etc/default/locale 
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_LOVE.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

But we may not want to reboot to take effect, so we can just source it to environment variable in current shell session:

```
$ . /etc/default/locale
```

How about `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` ? If you play around it you will know this command basically act as GUI to simplify the above steps, i.e. Edit `/etc/locale.gen` -> `sudo locale-gen` -> `sudo update-locale LANG=en_LOVE.UTF-8`

For python, as long as `/etc/locale.gen` contains that locale candidate and `locale.gen` get compiled, `setlocale(category, locale)` should work without throws `locale.Error: unsupoorted locale setting`. You can check the correct string `en_US.UTF-8`/`en_US/....etc` to be set in `setlocale()`, by observing `/etc/locale.gen` file, and then uncomment and compile it as desired. `zh_CN GB2312` without dot in that file means the correct string is `zh_CN` and `zh_CN.GB2312`.

Comment: For my situation, the short answer is: 1. edit `/etc/locale.gen`, uncomment the `zh_CN.UTF-8` line; 2. `sudo locale-gen`.

Answer (score 2):

For Dockerfile, this works for me:

```
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

How to install locale-gen?

[docker ubuntu /bin/sh: 1: locale-gen: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760663/docker-ubuntu-bin-sh-1-locale-gen-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and **`"export LC_ALL=c"`**  **didn't work for me**.

Try **`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`** (it will work).

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a problem with the locale setting. To fix this as indicated by other answers you need to modify your locale.

On Mac OS X Sierra I found that the best way to do this was to modify the `~/bash_profile` file as follows:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

This change will not be immediately evident in your current cli session unless you reload the bash profile by using: `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu:

`$ sudo vi /etc/default/locale`

Add below setting at the end of file.

`LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on Fedora:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/locale.py", line 620, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

It turned out that the "glibc-all-langpacks" package was missing.

```
dnf install -y glibc-all-langpacks
```