# Format numbers as currency in Python

Tags: python, locale, currency-formatting

I learn from [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python), use the [locale](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) module to format numbers as currency. For instance,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import locale

value = 123456789

l = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')     # LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
s = locale.currency(value, grouping=True)   # 123 456 789,00 €

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8') 
s = locale.currency(value, grouping=True)   # $123,456,789.00

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')    # WHY? locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
s = locale.currency(value, grouping=True)
```

I'd like to format numbers to other currency, say `de_DE`. I encounter the issue `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` since the locale `de_DE` is not in the list of `locale -a`.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')        # locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
s = locale.currency(value, grouping=True)
```

One solution is to add this locale to my machine. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[babel.numbers](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html)

```
In [22]: from babel.numbers import format_decimal
In [23]:  format_decimal(12345, locale='de_DE')
Out[23]: u'12.345'

In [24]: format_decimal(1.2345, locale='sv_SE')
Out[24]: u'1,234'
```

Or in your case [format_currency](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html#babel.numbers.format_currency):

```
In [7]: from babel.numbers import format_currency

In [8]: print format_currency(1099.98, 'USD', locale='en_US')
$1,099.98

In [9]: print format_currency(1099.98, 'USD', locale='es_CO')
1.099,98 US$

In [10]: print format_currency(1099.98, 'EUR', locale='de_DE')
1.099,98 €
```

Comment: Thx. I just found [`babel.numbers.format_currency`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html) under your guide.

Comment: No worries, it is a pretty neat lib, it does a multitude of things. I added the link to format_currency and the doc example.

Comment: I know you can parse without the dollar sign if you pass the locale but  with `$123,456,789.00` I am not sure how or if you can handle that. http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html#parsing-numbers

Comment: Thx. It is not fair to ask a new question. So, I start a new question, [Format currency as numbers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580151/format-currency-as-numbers-in-python).

Comment: No prob, I actually have an idea for a parser that can work for any currency, I will give you a ping when I get something working but hopefully there is a nice lib already

Comment: Many thanks. Sadly, [Format local currency as numbers in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580151/format-local-currency-as-numbers-in-python) is labeled as duplicate. I don't think it is duplicate.

Comment: I reopened the question as it is certainly not a dupe, there is a lot more to going from a formatted currency string back to a decimal

Answer (score 4):

For reference (for those that are looking to format numbers similar to how you would format currency), you can use [locale.format_string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.format_string) to format numbers

```
value = 123456789

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE') 
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', value, True))
```

Would return

```
123.456.789,00
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on python 3.7.6.  I used the package babel and format_number instead.

Comment: It works with python 3.9 and 3.10, but you might need to add the locale to your OS. One can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` on Debian-based systems (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43203667/6281925).

Answer (score 1):

I know of two solutions to this:

**Babel**

Babel is the best solution because you can choose any currency, regardless of the locale.

The down side is that it's poorly documented.  To know all the options, you'll have to read the [Babel source code](https://github.com/python-babel/babel) for the function you want to use

Install Babel:

```
$ pip install Babel
```

How to use:

```py
import babel.numbers

amount = 123456789.123

print(babel.numbers.format_currency(amount, 'EUR', locale='fr_CA'))
# 123 456 789,12 €

print(babel.numbers.format_currency(amount, 'EUR', locale='en_CA'))
# €123,456,789.12

print(babel.numbers.format_currency(amount, '', locale='en_CA'))
# 123,456,789.12
```

**`localize.currency()`**

One limitation of `locale.currency()` is that it presumes the currency that matches the locale. For example `en_US => $/USD` and `fr_FR => €/EUR`  So you may want to use the `String.replace()` method to replace the currency symbol after if the displayed currency doesn't match the locale.

Based on the locale setting, for example `en_US` or `en_GB`, `fr_FR` or `fr_CA`, it will know:

- Which decimal separator to use (eg `100.00` vs `100,00`)
- Which thousands separator to use (eg `1,000` vs `1.000`)
- Which currency symbol to use (eg `$100` vs `€100` or `USD 100` vs `EUR 100`)
- Where to place the currency symbol (eg `$100` vs `100 $`)

```py
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')

amount = 123456789.123
grouping = True  # thousands separator

# '123.456.789,12 Eu'
locale.currency(amount, symbol=True, grouping=True, international=False)

# '123.456.789,12 EUR'
locale.currency(amount, symbol=True, grouping=True, international=False)

# '123.456,789'
locale.currency(amount, symbol=False, grouping=True)

# '123456,789'
locale.currency(amount, symbol=False, grouping=True)
```

The optional arguments are as follows

```py
# which currency symbol to use, and where to place it
symbol=True and international=True # => 'USD 100.00'
symbol=True and international=False # => '$100.00'
symbol=False # => '100.00'

# thousands separator
grouping = True # => '1000.00'
grouping = False # => '1,000.00'
```