# Python - Formatting items in a list of numbers to be strings with currency symbol

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers that are currency values that I would like to convert to currencies with symbol:

Current list

```
list = [200,4002,4555,7533]
```

Given below is what is returned if I print the above list:

```
[(Decimal('200'), Decimal('4002'), Decimal('4555'), Decimal('7533')]
```

Expected output

```
list = ['$200','$4,002','$4,555','$7,533'] <<--These are basically number formatted for 1000's separator with the currency symbol
```

Comment: The list you gave is not valid Python. Do you mean the items to be strings?

Comment: You do realize that the output will be a list of strings right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format numbers as currency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579712/format-numbers-as-currency-in-python)

Comment: @KlausD, yes that is what I am expecting as output

Comment: @Madi7 yes that is the expected output

Comment: Then I suggest you update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the output as strings:

```
In [123]: lst = [200,4002,4555,7533]

In [124]: [f'${cur:,}' for cur in lst]
Out[124]: ['$200', '$4,002', '$4,555', '$7,533']
```

Also don't name your variables as some built-in.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. I am getting an error `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__` when I try in my data.. Any thoughts as to what is causing that..

Comment: @scottmartin Which version of Python are you on?

Comment: using python 3.7

Comment: @scottmartin That's strange. How did you run it? Can you run it as I did in a fresh session?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running this in different environments, get the same result.. However if I use the sample list you used it works fine so I am not sure if it has to do with my data. But they are just numbers that I am trying to convert..

Comment: @scottmartin Then it's that. The logic here is pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using builtin names like `list` for variables. You also can't output in this format without converting to strings, like below:

```
l = [200, 4002, 4555, 7533]

l = ['${:0,.0f}'.format(x) for x in l]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['$200', '$4,002', '$4,555', '$7,533']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually formatting the values in your list to strings containing currency representations, it's a good idea to use standard library functions that are dedicated to exactly this job. Here, what you may want to use are the functions from the `locale` module. These functions provide a convenient way for instance to represent dates, times, and currencies in a format that is appropriate for the current locale settings. The locale can be either set by the operating system of the computer the program runs on, or by the programmer of the program itself.

The first thing you have to do is load the `locale` module. Then you set up the locale setting, either to the system default:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")   # to use the system-wide locale setting
```

or to a locale of your own choosing:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.utf-8")   # to use the USA locale
```

Now, you can use the `currency` function to format a value using the current locale setting:

```
lst = [200, 4002, 4555, 7533]
cur_lst = [locale.currency(val) for val in lst]

print(cur_list)
['$200.00', '$4002.00', '$4555.00', '$7533.00']
```

The `currency` function has three options that allow you to tweak the output. The `grouping` option will insert appropriate grouping marks to separate thousands, millions etc.:

```
locale.currency(123456, grouping=True)
'$123,456.00'

locale.currency(123456, grouping=False)  # the default
'$123456.00'
```

The `international` option uses the international standard currency abbreviation instead of the currency symbol:

```
locale.currency(123456, international=True)
'USD 123456.00'

locale.currency(123456, international=False)  # the default
'$123456.00'
```

Lastly, setting the `symbol` option to `True` suppresses showing the currency symbol altogether.