# docker ubuntu /bin/sh: 1: locale-gen: not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I put the locale setting codes below into my dockerfile,

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

# Set the locale
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

but it gives me the error

```
/bin/sh: 1: locale-gen: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c locale-gen en_US.UTF-8' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

any idea?

Comment: Maybe you have to install `locales` using `sudo apt-get -y install locales`?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/801162

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Thanks for [your comment, edwinksl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760663/docker-ubuntu-bin-sh-1-locale-gen-not-found#comment66817293_39760663). I updated my dockerfile below which solved the locale-gen error:

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

# Set the locale
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: For efficiency you'll want to avoid multiple `RUN` statements, especially when they are closely related like this.  Something like `RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y locales && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` would create a single layer instead of three.

Comment: Maybe `update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is also useful https://askubuntu.com/a/505424/196423

Comment: For keeping your sanity, you'll want to avoid stashing all you commands together in one RUN

Comment: @mihai thankfully, bash lets you break commands into multiple lines with `/`. you'll actually want to do this and keep them all in one `RUN`, otherwise you will pollute your local environment with hundreds of useless layers.

Comment: @mihai's advice should be packaged with a reminder about `docker system prune --all`

Answer (score 22):

```
apt-get install -y locales
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
```

localedef is also good to use.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's the only thing that set the perl locale correctly of all the answers on this page!

Comment: This works for a ruby:3.2.2 image used in GitlabCI. Thanks!