# Unsupported locale setting error while pip install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I want to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` with pip on ubuntu 16.4. 
I have been install `python3.6`, `python3.7` and `python3.8` in my machine. 
I try these commands:

```
sudo python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
sudo python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
sudo python3.8 -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

But all of them made a a same error like this(notice this is error for run with `python3.7`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 608, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

**What should I do?**

> Also I couldn't install any package with pip !

Answer (score 0):

Your answer exist in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394101/pip-install-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting) question.

This error raise since you didn't set `lacales` vaiables in your system. Run this line of code in your `bash`:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope its help!