# Parse date and change format from spanish

Tags: python, date, format

This might be a duplicated question but since I have read all
the comments about it and I don't solve my question I have to ask again.

I am working with a dataframe where I Have a column with this look:

```
print final['fecha_dato'][2]
```

31 de Enero del 2017

I do this in order to make it more understandable:

```
d = final['fecha_dato'][2]
d = d.replace(' de ','-')
d = d.replace(' del ','-')
```

And i get this output:
'31-Enero-2017'

I want to convert it to 31-01-2017 format and I try this in order to make the
Spanish understandable:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
```

but it says: unsupported locale setting.

Once i've done this I guess I will have to do something like this:

```
datetime.strptime('6-Mar-2016', '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Let's see what is the problem. If you can give me a way of using the replace
in just one sentence that would be great too.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Comment: `d = d.replace(' de ','-').replace(' del ','-')` works in a single line, and even better: `d = final['fecha_dato'][2].replace(' de ','-').replace(' del ','-')` also works.

Comment: There's no need to use the `.replace` method, let the `.strptime` method take care of that. OTOH, if the amount of whitespace is variable you may wish to split & re-join the string to make it use single spaces (or some other separator of your choice) between fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably on Windows, where the locale code is different. First you parse the locale so you can read the date string properly, using the appropriate code:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'esp_esp')
```

Then, as you guessed, you parse the string to get a date object using `strptime`, and you convert it back to a string using the format you want with `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
date = dt.strptime('31 de Enero del 2017', '%d de %B del %Y')
date_str = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I tried this but I used it on a wrong way as I was trying to do it with a wrong code on setlocales as I coulndt see the right one on the documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line because your output date format is purely numeric, assuming your OS locale database is set up properly.

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')

print(datetime.strptime('31 de Enero del 2017', '%d de %B del %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

**output**

```
2017-01-31
```

If you want to output a date containing day &/or month names you need to do it in two stages so you can switch locales.

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')
s = '31 de Enero del 2017'
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%d de %B del %Y')

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
print(d.strftime('%A, %B %d %Y'))
```

**output**

```
Tuesday, January 31 2017
```