# Convert spanish date into a pandas datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I want to convert this df from an object to a datetime object, "ABR" is the Spanish for "APR"

| Initial date | final date |
| --- | --- |
| 30 ABR 21 | 31 MAY 21 |
| 30 JUN 21 | 31 JUL 21 |

my code:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
a["Fecha Inicial"].apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(x, "%d %b %y"))
```

ValueError

```
ValueError: time data '30 ABR 21' does not match format '%d %b %y'
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed OP mentioned `"ABR" is the Spanish for "APR"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date and change format from spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760474/parse-date-and-change-format-from-spanish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can solve your issue

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

a = pd.DataFrame({"Fecha Inicial": ['30 ABR 21', '30 JUN 21']})

mapping_dict = {'ENERO':'JAN',
'FEB':'FEB',
'MARZO':'MAR',
'ABR':'APR',
'MAYO':'MAY',
'JUN':'JUN',
'JUL':'JUL',
'AGOSTO':'AUG',
'SEPT':'SEP',
'OCT':'OCT',
'NOV':'NOV',
'DIC':'DEC'
                }

a["Fecha Inicial"].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x.replace(x.split(' ')[1],mapping_dict[x.split(' ')[1]].capitalize()), "%d %b %y"))
```

`locale` has some issue that affects the `dt.datetime.strptime`.

Comment: I think the `apply` makes for a pretty hard read, simpler: `pd.to_datetime(a["Fecha Inicial"].replace(mapping_dict, regex=True))`

Comment: perfect @MrFuppes, did you try that one. Please add here. will help full for all

Comment: it works fine in your example, feel free to integrate it into your answer  :)