# Converting a string into a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to convert a string with this format "25 de mayo de 2023 14:53 hs." into a datetime, I've used the method:

```
df['Fecha_de_venta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_de_venta'])
```

but the output says the string format is unexpected. Is there any method I can use in order to transform it into a know string to then transform it into a datetime.

Comment: It seems like your datetime format doesn't match the format that pandas expects. I'd look into [python regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or python's datetime function [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) is a regex for datetimes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date and change format from spanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760474/parse-date-and-change-format-from-spanish)

Answer (score 3):

To convert a string with the format "25 de mayo de 2023 14:53 hs." into a datetime object, you can use the strptime function from the datetime module.

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "25 de mayo de 2023 14:53 hs."
date_format = "%d de %B de %Y %H:%M hs."

# Set the appropriate locale for month names
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')

# Parse the string into a datetime object
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)

print(datetime_object)
```

[EDIT]
If you want to convert a full column of data, use this code instead:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Set the appropriate locale for month names
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8')

# Define the conversion function
def convert_to_datetime(date_string):
    date_format = "%d de %B de %Y %H:%M hs."
    return datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {'Fecha_de_venta': ['25 de mayo de 2023 14:53 hs.', '26 de junio de 2023 10:30 hs.', '27 de julio de 2023 18:45 hs.']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Apply the conversion function to the column
df['Fecha_de_venta'] = df['Fecha_de_venta'].apply(convert_to_datetime)

print(df['Fecha_de_venta'])
```

Comment: Hey! thanks a lot, it did worked. But I forgot to say that I must convert a full column of data.

Answer (score 0):

For using it directly into pandas like you asked.

Try this:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8")

import pandas as pd
df['Fecha_de_venta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha_de_venta'], format="%d de %B de %Y %H:%M hs.")
```

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0La5.png)

Comment: This comes as an error:

TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: This code doesn´t work at all for me. Maybe my edited post works for you

Comment: Sorry, the error is:

ValueError: time data '25 de mayo de 2023 14:53 hs.' does not match format '%d de %B de %Y %H:%M hr.' (match)

Comment: There was a typo in my `locale` spelling, please check now, this works for me.

Comment: @mjmoralesf There is a typo in your comment.
your comment mentions "%d de %B de %Y %H:%M hr." `hr` instead of `hs` which is in your original question, correct your typo and this solution will be smooth for you, check my screenshot.

Comment: @mjmoralesf If it doesn't work for you, check out my answer