# How to set locale in AWS AMI Linux Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-ami

I have a small script in python, that make use of locale to format a number from 1.000,00 to 1,000.00

```
import re, locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_PE.UTF-8')

locale.atof(number)
```

Then when I run this in Lambda, I get this error message:

**unsupported locale setting**

I know how to install the dependencies in my PC by executing this commands in the terminal:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36257050/2513972

Comment: How are AMIs, which are an EC2 feature, related to AWS Lambda here?

Comment: Lambdas do have an AMI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html  But you are correct in pointing out that Lambda is more of a managed service and not really setup for you to be customing or installing things on.  It does allow for limited customization though.

Answer (score 0):

For detereming the list of available locales see https://phrase.com/blog/posts/beginners-guide-to-locale-in-python/

```
for lang in locale.locale_alias.values():
    print(lang)
```

You won't be able to "install" anything in the default AWS Lambda Python Runtime Environment and setting up a custom runtime is probably more trouble than it's worth.  You can see if there is something else you can use.

If you really are just converting 1.000,00 to 1,000.00 I recommend instead just running your own character replacement.  A simple character check loop wouldn't be any slower than `atof` and would have less side effects.

If your curious about how `atof` works you can follow it's source code trace in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/locale.py#L336

If you don't want to use your own character replace you can use `format` with a custom `format_spec`.

```
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(10000)
'10,000.00'
```

This next line pretty much follows the same steps at `atof`.  Delocalize with replacements then float.

```
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(float('10.000,00'.replace('.','').replace(',','.')))
'10,000.00'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

If you you really want to customize your lambda runtime see the following:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html