# india currency locale not working in locale python

Tags: python-2.7, formatting, locale, currency, currency-formatting

trying **locale.setlocale('locale.LC_ALL, 'en_IN')** and it's not working
throwing error **locale.Error: unsupported locale setting**
tried using utf-8 encoding too, 
all suggestions are welcomed
I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a locale in Python if your OS has this locale available. So you'd have to update your locales on the OS level. See [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting/36257050) for a description how to do this in Linux, for example.

Comment: @prk190 On Mac, this is in System Preferences::Languages & Regions::+ (plus sign under the list).