# Python3 issue with unicode

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I can't seem to get the unicode representation of utf-8 characters on a production server, although it works well the development workstation.

### When I use Python 3.6.9 [GCC 8.3.0] on linux (Ubuntu server).

```
>>> str('\u0394')
'\u0394'

>>>print('\u0394')               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

### When I use Python 3.6.5 [GCC 4.2.1] on darwin (Mac OS)

```
>>> str('\u0394')
'Δ'

>>> print('\u0394') 
Δ
```

By the look of it, I'd say that there is something broken on the ubuntu server as `str()` is suppose to convert to unicode in Python 3. However, it could well be that things work differently in revision 3.6.9 w.r.t.  3.6.5. Any tips on how could I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: You're missing a character set to display the character you want. It's a matter of either configuring your Ubuntu system and/or installing characters set(s) you need - more likely just installing ttf fonts package(s) will fix it.  Maybe this will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/689607/how-do-i-resolve-missing-characters-in-my-unicode-font

Comment: str('\u0394') and '\u0394' are exactly the same. Your *viewer* (terminal) is incapable to display the Unicode character, supporting only the Latin1 character set.

Comment: Installing the ttf fonts didn't help, but your comment about the character set in ubuntu led me to the fix as described bellow. Thanks @Todd!

Comment: Awesome. Glad you found a fix. You're welcome. Maybe an update to the title of the question will help others find this who run into this on their Ubuntu distros.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix amending the locale to match `.UTF-8` as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36257050/1128549):

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Previously `/etc/default/locale` only had `en_US`. I have changed it in the locale file as well, but since I can not reboot at the moment, the commands above are the best fix for me.