# How to fix issue "Error: unsupported locale setting"

Tags: python

When I'm run my python script, I have the following issue :  "Error: unsupported locale setting".
It happened when the line run :

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf8")`

I tried to fix the issue with some solutions find on internet but it doesn't work...
I'm on OS X.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python locale error: unsupported locale setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Comment: On Mac you could try `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.ISO8859-1")`

Comment: It work for me with that solution, thanks a lot !