# How to fix error "Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session." after Update to Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I update to the Android studio to 4.2.1 and not debug and get I cannot do that because of this message which is Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapplication | com.example.myapplication.test. After sometime Could not connect to remote processes. Aborting debug session is shown. But I install Android studio 4.1.1 again and easy debug. I read all questions and not found the best way to fix plz help me, thanks all

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602854/android-studio-debugger-process-finished-with-exit-code-127

Comment: @michael-sotnikov this solution is in linux

Answer (score 4):

For developers who are living in Iran, it's related to sanctions. After the version 4.2 release, Google use more ways to identify where we are from either or both the Region and Regional Format. Therefore you should change them to another country and then update sdk to solve the problem.

To change region to United States in Windows 10:

Setting -> Time & Language -> Region, then select United States in the country or region drop down.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you.
I am facing this issue from months ago, but any other solution didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing country and region language and using proxy worked 4 me.

Answer (score 0):

**Invalidate cache and restart** should help.