# Android NDK debugging with Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

When creating a new project using the Android Studio Native C++ template I'm unable to debug the project on any device I own. Logcat reports not much info as to why.

Are there any extra steps I need to take to setup breakpoint debugging?

Could someone try create a new native template using android studio and see if they can get it debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio was also reporting:
`Debugger process finished with exit code 127. A library required by the native debugger might be missing on your system. See idea.log file for more details.`

I found this stackoverflow post after a quick google:

[Android Studio Debugger process finished with exit code 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602854/android-studio-debugger-process-finished-with-exit-code-127)

I couldn't find libncurses5 on my current distribution: Fedora, so instead opted to symlink the v6 libraries to v5:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libncurses6.so /usr/lib64/libncurses5.so
```

After doing this for all libraries listed in the `idea.log` (one after another) I was able to get debugging working in Android Studio